# How to run a HTTP Go program on my BlueHost server

Tags: http, server, hosting

I am working on HTTP handling with Go. I know how to serve files and stuff on localhost, but I have no clue how to get this stuff to work on, let's say, my website www.foo.com. I attached following theoretical code that I would like to launch (basically saying "Hey" every time someone goes onto my website).

My first thought is that BlueHost (my host) must already be serving file directories in order for us to access the website, right? That means would we not use `http.ListenAndServe(...)`? Also, why wouldn't `http.ListenAndServe("www.foo.com", nil)` work?

I haven't tried anything on my Bluehost yet as I'm afraid of screwing up something. I've thought about just uploading my main.go but then I realized I would have no way to run it! Do I upload it as an .exe instead?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) { fmt.Println("Hey") })
    http.ListenAndServe(":42069", nil)
}
```

Comment: What kind of hosting plan do you have? Is it a VPS or just for web hosting?

Comment: To your question about how to run it, it would be best to build the program and upload it to the server. The obvious benefit being that you don't need to have Go installed on the server for it to work.

Comment: you should close this question and ask a new one over at sibling site  https://serverfault.com  ...  path of least resistance is to rent yourself a remote vps server for say $15 a month ... choose Ubuntu 18.04 then from your local box ssh onto remote box and install golang  then git clone your github.com repo where your code lives ... then compile your source ... initially you will have just an IP like 123.123.123 or some such so your url will look like http://123.123.123/  .. then buy a domain name so you have http://matthewnazari.com/   .. then get yourself tls certs etc .. its called devops